# pyodbc cursor.execute (query) adds my username in front of the table from database

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

In Jupyter Notebook, I was able to connect to my work database using pyobdc with 'dsn; userid; pw' connection string successfully.  I tested out printing all the table names in the database.  Then I tried to run the following code to test a simple query.

================================

```
query = "select * from TEST_TABLE"

cursor.execute(query)
```

================================

But I got the following error.

```
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0204N  "**myusername.TEST_TABLE**" is an **undefined name**.  SQLSTATE=42704\r\n (-204) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

TEST_TABLE does exist in the database I'm connected to. But for some reason, the code is adding `myusername` in front of the `TEST_TABLE` and tells me the table name is not defined.

Comment: Does `print([[tbl.table_schem, tbl.table_name] for tbl in cursor.tables("TEST_TABLE")])` show that the table is in some schema other than `myusername`?

Comment: Thank you!  This did help me locate the problem.  The code revealed that there are multiple schemas in the data source.  None of them is myusername.  After adding the right schema in front of the table, I was able to run the query successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the PyODBC connection as follows:

```
import pyodbc
dbConn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=<dsn>;UID=<uid>;PWD=<pwd>;DATABASE=<db>")
dbCursor = dbConn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE"
dbCursor.execute(query)
```

where:

- *dsn* = the hostname (or IP address)
- *uid* = the username
- *pwd* = the password
- *db* = the database name

Comment: Thank you!  I tried the code.  Not sure if it's because I wasn't specifying database correctly or some other reason, the error continued and still pointed to myusername schema.